# How do I show every n-th label to handle long x-axis labels in fusionCharts?

Tags: javascript, fusioncharts

I have to plot a fusion chart for 30 days data. But because of too many data points, a scroll bar is coming. So I just want to plot every nth label. Inorder to reduce my x-axis size.

The fusion chart code is here :

```
 var ecuChart = new FusionCharts({
                    //type: 'mscolumn3d',
                    type: 'scrollline2d',
                    //type: 'msarea',
                    renderAt: 'ecuGraphBody',
                    width: "265",
                    height: "100%",
                    dataFormat: "json", 
                    dataSource: {
                        "chart": {
                            "subcaption": "Graph",
                            "xAxisname": "day",
                            "yAxisName": " $/Hour",
                            "numvisibleplot": "24",
                            "animation":"1",                           
                            "decimals":"2",
                            "showLegend": "1",
                            "numberprefix": "$",
                            "legendPosition": "bottom",
                            "legendIconScale":"1",
                            "theme":"fint",
                            "legendshadow": "0",
                            "exportenabled": "1",
                            "legendborderalpha": "0",
                            //"palettecolors": "#f8bd19,#008ee4,#33bdda,#e44a00,#6baa01,#583e78",
                            "showborder": "0",
                            "showValues": "1",
                            "labelStep" :"4"
                        },

                        "categories": [
                                       {
                                           "category": categories
                                       }
                                    ],
                       "dataset": [
                                     {
                                           "data": graphdata
                                     }
                                  ]


                    }
                }).render();


graphdata: [
                {
                    "value": "15123"
                },
                {
                    "value": "14233"
                },
                {
                    "value": "23507"
                },
                {
                    "value": "9110"
                },
                {
                    "value": "15529"
                },
                {
                    "value": "20803"
                },
                {
                    "value": "19202"
                }
                .
                .
                .
                ]

categories : [
                {
                    "label": "1"
                },
                {
                    "label": "2"
                },
                {
                    "label": "3"
                },
                {
                    "label": "4"
                },
                {
                    "label": "5"
                },
                {
                    "label": "6"
                },
                {
                    "label": "7"
                }
                .
                .
                .
                .
                {
                   "label": "30"
                }]
```

Comment: I think it's better to filter every nth data before passing it to the chart object

Comment: use `$.grep` to filter the graphdata and categories based on the `n` you have in mind

Comment: @adiga with $.grep it works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the attribute `labelStep` and define how many labels you want to skip. You will get the details from this [link](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-attributes.html?chart=msline)

Comment: I tried using labelStep. It just reduces the number of labels shown on x-axis, but doesn't reduces the number of plotted points, because of which my x-axis size is still the same.

Comment: If you do not want to show labels as well as data, you should not have it in the data itself. There is no way to determine which data point to keep and which to skip. Hope this help. If you have a separate concern, space or performance, for large data, then let me know.

Comment: Yeah I have used that solution only. Before plotting the data, I am parsing it based on my required number of points. Thanks